# HTML Table creator in metabox to put into post theme

Tags: metabox, html

I'm looking for a funcionality of creating HTML Table in metabox in post-editing page to put into post theme with a shortcode or something similar?

http://alexrabe.de/wordpress-plugins/wp-table/ is almost perferc, but I need this table creator while post editing...

it could act similar to custom fields:

title1 | value1
title2 | value2
title3 | value3

etc..

Answer (score 1):

This plugin adds many useful (and some less useful) to TinyMCE, table editor among them:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/

It also gives you full control over what buttons are shown and where in the editor, so it might be good to install it in any case.

Comment: or plugin "Add Quicktag" for the html-editor; you can define custom strings for a button on the editor.

Answer (score 1):

My [shortcode plugin](https://github.com/toscho/WordPress-Shortcodes) supports simple tables. You write them straight into the post editor, not into a meta box. Depending on your needs this may be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just looking for solution and I have 2 ways to realize that matter.

I need to build a table in post edition page somewhere in metabox.

Solutions:
1. metabox with different type of custom fields
2. metabox with wysiwyg editor to build 2-columns table

Table would look exactly like it was made with custom fields: 
label | value
label | value
etc..

I need to manage these table on post-editing site.

Would you have any suggestions please?

BR

Comment: if i was the enduser i would like option 2 if my mother was the enduser i would like option 1 :)

Comment: yes, but have you got any idea how to make both ?